# How to launch android gallery app using adb shell?

Tags: android, shell, adb

I tried a lot and  got

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity
```

for launching browser so I tried the same with gallery and I'm stuck with this

```
adb shell  am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.sec.android.gallery3d/.GalleryActivity</b><br/>
```

I know GalleryActivity is not available but what else can i use?

Note: I am using samsung Galaxy S3 mini so the package name is com.sec.android.gallery3d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use monkey to open any app through adb shell,

Try the below command,

```
$ adb shell monkey -p com.android.gallery3d 1
```

In my nexus4, Gallery app package name is com.android.gallery3d and we are just passing 1 event via monkey, So that monkey will just open the app and will not do anything further.

Also this approach helps you to open any app just with the package name. Monkey will pick the launcher activity by itself.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

maybe

```
adb shell am start  -t image/* -a android.intent.action.VIEW
```

also one more thing , this will open the default app selected for gallery in your device.